# User.identity .name is empty

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am getting `user.identity.name` empty in web application using forms authentication after authenticating through memberships.

I redirect it to other form but how to keep track of which user is logged in, i am not using session. Is there another way?

```
MembershipUser oCurrentUser = Membership.GetUser();
Response.Write(oCurrentUser.UserName);
```

In this also it is giving me `nullreference exception` ,though it is validating properly

```
bCheckUser = Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
```

this is returning true.

Comment: Can you share more code from your login code-behind where you are authenticating and setting cookie? Also you are trying to get User.Identity on same page or different? Even some settings in forms authentication section in your web.config could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx)()

Once `Membership.ValidateUser()` is true you should set the `authentication ticket` (using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie) and then you'll be able to get the `User.Identity` object on any other page.

Comment: this cookie is set after validating user and how to use it in other forms, can u give any reference link..

Comment: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx