# Why is User.Identity null after Membership.ValidateUser returns true?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider, asp.net-mvc-5.1

It is unfortunate I have to deal with `MembershipProvider` in the days of MVC5. But here is the problem that confuses me.

In my MVC application, the login view post the username and password back to the Login controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginInputModel model)
    {   
        var isValid = Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password);
        var user = Membership.GetUser(model.Username);
        var isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        ...
    }
```

Step into the controller, I find

- `isValid` is `true`, which is good.
- `user` returns correct information also.

But

- `isAuthenticated` is `false`
- `User.Identity` is still `null`.

I always thought `Membership.ValidateUser()` will populated User.Identity` with correct info. Now it appears there is something missing. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, if `User.Identity` *is* null, then `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` (used to find `isAuthenticated`) throws an exception, no?

Answer (score 0):

The User object will not be populated until the next request. User is part of the HttpContext which has not been updated yet.

Seeing that you're not using WebSecurity (which would be nice here) you'll have to set the auth cookie after validation.

```
if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
{
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
     //Any other logic you need to perform
} 
else
{
     //Handle invalid login details
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think you are pointing at the correct direction. But how can I update `User` in `HttpContext`?

Comment: I misread your code a bit. You will need to SetAuthCookie in order for it to work. ValidateUser only checks to see if the username/password combo is correct. You then need to set the auth cookie. I've updated my answer. Another option is to use WebSecurity.Login which handles all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my temporary workaround:

It is inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556970/user-identity-name-is-empty).

I added a statement:

```
if (user != null) FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
```

It appears to be working. But I am not sure if this is the correct way.